# Open-source replacement for Amazon EBS for own cluster

Tags: debian, nfs, amazon-ebs

I have a couple of worker nodes running Linux, on which I dynamically provision KVM virtual machines. Right now, I copy the qcow2 images from the NFS server to the node, run the VM and after shutdown the image gets moved back to the NFS server.

Is there a way to avoid the "copy" step (thanks to 10G networking, it's fast, but not instant) and use something like Amazon's EBS service, preferrably with a "block cache" on the local SSD of the nodes?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to have dived into the detail without giving the big picture. Not everyone knows what things like qcow2 are, so if you can explain what that is you may get more people able to help. Suggest you edit your question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The qcow2 image is the raw disk image - given that the VM image sizes run up to 50GB, this is the reason why I want to load their data on-demand via network than copying it before / after VM launch.

Comment: Why copy the entire image back? You could export a directory on the NFS server and mount it on the node. No need to copy data to and from the node.

Comment: @ThoriumBR does NFSv3 (the NAS does not provide NFSv4) support random seeking on a gigabyte-sized image or will it (or rather, cachefilesd) copy the entire file instead?

Comment: Don't use the image, export the filesystem. It will be fast, unless your files are several GB's in size. NFSv3 supports random reads and random writes on GB sized files, and you can use cachefilesd.

Comment: Well, the images *are* huge (10GB and upwards, biggest one at 50GB), and to make it worse the guest VMs are a mixture of Windows and Linux so no export of the filesystem (and I'm not even sure if it's possible to get Windows to boot over a network without weeks worth of customizing). I just dont want to risk trying it out and frying my network ;)